# Cairo-Dock crashed my Unity desktop, is this possible?

Tags: boot, unity, 14.04, desktop-environments, cairo-dock

I'm still new to using Ubuntu and learning more and more each day. The other day I formatted my hard drive and wiped the Windows 8 partition (never use it) and re-installed my Ubuntu install to start fresh.

Any way, I installed Cairo-Dock, thinking that I would give it a try after installing. After using it for a bit I shut computer down, and came back later to turn it on, and the unity desktop wasn't loading.

Is this a common problem with Cairo or just a bug in Ubuntu all together? After I did the fix in the Terminal Cairo wasn't working properly, so I just removed it all together - I didn't want to waste time with it. I would rather have my computer running.

Comment: How did you install Cairo, and what happened when the 'unity desktop wasn't loading', and how did you fix it in terminal? If this is a bug it is likely a bug with Cario.

Comment: This is an interesting question to me because I've always imagined one would use Cairo-Dock to move away from Unity.  Cairo-Dock provides a 'display manager' option on the login screen.  I normally see users using this or `gnome-session-flashback` display manager selected while running Cairo-Dock.

Answer (score 0):

You could check this - if this following works better in the end
(It is unknown if your machine has enough RAM and enough space on harddisk):

a) install window-manager xfce4 with

> sudo apt-get install xfce4

then let display-manager there be adjusted at light-dm

plus b) after a) is settled then install window-manager gnome and gdm with

> sudo apt-get install gnome gdm

then adjust the display-manager now at gdm (there is a query during installation which display-manager you want to use - there adjust this to 'gdm' in the given little menue)

and reboot your machine.

Back into terminal you can (you have not to do this) remove unity with

> sudo apt-get remove unity

Now cairo-dock would work together with gnome, or you let unity there be present as option for later, in case above window-managers are not pleasing you. But all I can say is, that gnome is working fine with cairo-dock.